# find app released date in android

Tags: android, google-play

How to find the release date of an app in the android market? I want to know when some apps with a big number of downloads where release to have a look on how long it took them to get there.

Answer (score 2):

The app itself doesn't have a date (as far as I can see) but the comments do. So you can be sure the app is at least as old as the oldest comment on it.